# Greek handwriting font with math and (optional) TikZ support

Tags: math-mode, fonts, greek

I have been searching for several days for a handwriting font in LaTeX which is capable of:

- supporting greek language - either babel+inputenc or babel+utf8 or any possible combination;
- supporting math content;
- optionally, supporting Tikz plots etc.

However, I have not managed to find something - e.g. Google's hand.sty is not compatible with greek fonts (or I haven't found the way to make it work).

So, are there any suggestions?

P.S.: I have no problem to switch from (pdf)LaTeX to some other engine (e.g. LuaTex etc) in order to achieve this.

Comment: Are you able to use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX? That opens up a lot more possibilities.

Comment: Yes, of course!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don’t know of any handwritten font specifically designed for math, or legacy LaTeX encodings.  However, the `unicode-math` project lets you mix and match any OpenType and TrueType fonts.

Here, I’ve kitbashed the letters from [VAG Handwritten](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/VAG-HandWritten) and filled in numbers and some math symbols from [Tillana](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/tillana).  Any symbols not in these fall back to GFS Neohellenic Math.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
% Tillana is a free font by the Indian Type Foundry, available at:
% https://github.com/itfoundry/tillana/
% VAG Handwritten is a free font by VAG Design, available at:
% https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/VAG-HandWritten
\setmainfont{VAG-HandWritten.otf}
\setmathfont{GFS Neohellenic Math}
\setmathfont[range={"03C0, "2013-"2014, "2018-"201A, "201C-"201E, "2021-"2022,
                    "2026, "2030, "2039-"203A, "2044, "20AC, "20BA, "20BD,
                    "2113, "2122, "2126, "212E, "2202, "2206, "220F, "2211,
                    "2212, "2215, "221A, "221E, "222B, "2246, "2260, "2264,
                    "2265, "25CA}
            ]{Tillana-Regular.ttf}
\setmathfont[range=bfup/{Latin,latin,num}
            ]{Tillana-Semibold.ttf}
\setmathfont[range={"00-"FF,
                    up/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek},
                    \increment}
            ]{VAG-HandWritten.otf}
\setmathfont[range=up/num
            ]{Tillana-Regular.ttf}

\begin{document}

\[ \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}
   \int_0^{2 \muppi} \frac{t^2}{2} \mathop{\symup{d}t} \leq
   \sum_{i=1}^N  \frac{\muppi i}{\sqrt 2} \approx \increment \symbfup{v}t \]

\[ \frac{\sin \theta}{\Theta} =
   \frac{\sin \varphi}{\Phi} = 
   \frac{\sin \gamma}{\Gamma} \]

\end{document}
```

[image: VAG Handwritten/Tillana/GFS Neohellenic Math sample]

The widely-available handwritten font with the biggest repertoire of symbols is—you might want to sit down for this, don’t get mad at me, I’m just the messenger—Comic Sans.  And some physicists do use it for their presentation slides.  You might also have a look at [Pecita](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Pecita).  But you can sub in any handwritten Greek font of your choice with a command like

```
\setmathfont[range=up/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek,num}]{Some Font}
```

Comment: Trying to compile the above with XeLaTeX I get: "Package fontspec Error: The font "GFS Neohellenic Math" cannot be found. \setmathfont".

Comment: It’s on CTAN as the `gfsneohellenicmath` package, might also be available in a package from your OS, and if all else fails can be downloaded [from the GFS](https://greekfontsociety-gfs.gr/typefaces/Math).

Comment: @ΒασίληςΜάρκος Try `tlmgr install gfsneohellenicmath` if you’re using TeX Live. Or on Debian/Ubuntu, `apt install texlive-fonts-extra`.

Comment: It returned "Cannot determine type of tlpdb from /home/bill/texmf!". I will check this again later. Anyway, thanks for your help! I may need your help later on, though! :)

Comment: Also, on LuaLaTex, I get "Dimension too large. \setmathfont".

Comment: @ΒασίληςΜάρκος It works for me on TeX Live 2019.

Comment: Running it on ubuntu returned "E: Unable to locate package texlive-fonts-extr".

Comment: @ΒασίληςΜάρκος Typo.

Comment: That was right. Even so, I get "texlive-fonts-extra is already the newest version (2018.20190227-1)."

Comment: @ΒασίληςΜάρκος Okay, you’re using Disco. That package should have installed `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/gfsneohellenicmath/GFSNeohellenicMath.otf`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103611/discussion-between-davislor-and--).

Comment: @Davislor Wow, wonderful works and very very nice. +1