# "Realistic" Hand-written Maths Fonts

Tags: math-mode, fonts, amsmath, fontspec

I was looking through this website:

http://chalkdustmagazine.com/blog/is-there-a-perfect-maths-font/

And I was wondering if there is the equivalent of producing a math font as shown in Example 1 in the image below?

It looks neat, clean, but also much more "personal" due to the hand-drawn nature. The image in the link was drawn by a staff member, and as far as I can tell, I can't find a math font latex package which produces some font like this.

[image]

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/453429 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/525338.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a Handwriting environment for both text and Math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453429/create-a-handwriting-environment-for-both-text-and-math)