# Latex font like the one in this shirt?

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

Pmuch the title, i want to know if there is a latex font package that looks somwehat like this:
[image]

Comment: [Does this help?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/525356/61644)

Comment: it helps yes, it might be a little hard to find all the substitutions for any missing symbols, but it's useful.

Comment: Don’t blame me, I’m just the messenger, but the handwriting-style font with the best repertoire of math symbols is, uh, Comic Sans.

Comment: So... It has come to this...